# Add a border to Bootstrap panel's header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is how my panel looks like:
[image]

Can I add a blue border around panel's header?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your panel code?

Comment: assuming it's the default panel like http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels just use `.panel-default>.panel-heading { border: 4px solid blue; }`

Comment: Yes, that works. Just one more thing. What if I want to make it work across the whole system? How can I modify bootstrap.css?

Comment: if you apply that to your site's CSS file, it should overwrite all bootstrap panel headers. You don't want to modify bootstrap.css itself - you want to create your own stylesheet that you load after bootstrap that overwrite's bootstrap's stuff. That way you can update the bootstrap css file  with updates from bootstrap without worrying about overwriting your custom css.

Comment: I agree, but what if I would want to use different themes where a blue color might not be appropriate and I need to use different color?

Comment: what would be the problem with changing "blue" to "red" (or whatever) in the css I gave you if you wanted to use a different theme?